# Possible to lookup a Sharepoint list in Access?

Tags: lookup-column, access

I am trying to make a very large list of records with about 1,000 items or more added monthly, and I was told that it would be better to use an Access table instead of a Sharepoint list for so many items. It is a list of servicings for devices, and we already have the devices in a Sharepoint list that is continuously updated. Is there any way to pull up the devices from the Sharepoint list from an Access form, for easier data entry? I know how lookups look in Sharepoint but relationships in Access are more complicated. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is a datasheet view that you may be interested in. Every SharePoint List has a datasheet view that acts like Access or an Excel spreadsheet so that data sorts in a row/column format.

1. Go to the list you want to access.
2. Go to the top of the page and click the "List" tab.
3. Click DataSheet View.

Comment: To whoever downvoted, can you explain what's wrong with this answer? SharePoint datasheet view can be used in conjunction with SharePoint view filtering/sorting and can still be a nifty way to access your data fast and effectively edit in bulk.

Comment: Trolls.  I am an anti-troll. +1.  I don't see anything wrong with your answer; it is not a solution in line with the OP's direct question, but it *is* a workaround, which in many cases can at least help the user accomplish his end goal.  Besides, Sharepoint dunces don't have 2500+ points.